# How to trigger a mouse click on partial Element using jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <td class="GNEB1S-HKB" valign="middle">
     <div style="white-space: normal;line-height:1.2;font-size:10px;width:100px; color:#969696;" id="DOM_110">
           <div title="15 of 212 items were loaded. Click to load all items.">212 found<br>
                 <span style="text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer" onclick="return handleEvent(event,'com.polarion.alm.tracker.web.js.internal.TrackerNew68/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLComposite69/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLContainer70/com.polarion.alm.tracker.web.js.internal.trackercards.TrackerCardTree71/com.polarion.alm.tracker.web.js.internal.trackercards.TrackerCardTree$3375/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLComposite376/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLContainer377/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLSplitPane382/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLSplitPane378/com.polarion.alm.tracker.web.js.internal.treetable.TrackerTreeAndQP225/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLComposite227/com.polarion.alm.tracker.web.js.internal.treetable.TrackerTree217','click1913',false)">Load all</span>
         </div>
     </div>
 </td>
```

For a webpage I have the above as an element. The text at the end of the element **Load all** is *Clickable*. Using JQuery or JavaScript I want to click on that Load All.

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you add a class to your span?

Comment: If so, then `$('.spanClass').trigger("click")`

Comment: I can't modify the webpage. This problem is part of the bigger problem of taking a table and exporting it to CSV. This ***Load All*** loads all the rows of the table that I want to export.

Comment: Do you have any class or ID at the parent level which you can use?

Comment: @SandeepNayak  : Isn't GNEB1S-HKB a class for this element?

Comment: See my edited answer below. You can target the span element using GNEB1S-HKB class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 <span class="loader-class">....</span>
```

in jQuery:

```
 $(".GNEB1S-HKB span").trigger("click", function(evnt){
        //handle the click if needed here
        console.log("I have been clicked!!");
 });
```

OR if you can manage to add a class to the span element, like this,

```
 $(".loader-class").trigger("click", function(evnt){
        //handle the click if needed here
        console.log("I have been clicked!!");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

well ... in javascript you should do this ... 
but i don't know what your 'handleEvent' function does ...
anyway ... here's the code

```html
 <td class="GNEB1S-HKB" valign="middle">
     <div style="white-space: normal;line-height:1.2;font-size:10px;width:100px; color:#969696;" id="DOM_110">
           <div title="15 of 212 items were loaded. Click to load all items.">212 found<br>
                 <span id="loader" style="text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer" onclick="return handleEvent(event,'com.polarion.alm.tracker.web.js.internal.TrackerNew68/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLComposite69/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLContainer70/com.polarion.alm.tracker.web.js.internal.trackercards.TrackerCardTree71/com.polarion.alm.tracker.web.js.internal.trackercards.TrackerCardTree$3375/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLComposite376/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLContainer377/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLSplitPane382/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLSplitPane378/com.polarion.alm.tracker.web.js.internal.treetable.TrackerTreeAndQP225/com.polarion.reina.web.js.widgets.HTMLComposite227/com.polarion.alm.tracker.web.js.internal.treetable.TrackerTree217','click1913',false)">Load all</span>
         </div>
     </div>
 </td>

<script>
var myspan=document.getElementById("loader");
myspan.click();
</script>
```